# Confused by the meaning of this sentence + combination of "....とはまた違う" [MC is comparing his maid with his secretary]

Tags: grammar, meaning, japanese-to-english

Context : MC is comparing his maid with A (his secretary). She's the chief maid in his family, and used to be his nanny + personal tutor since he was still a little kid.

And I'm confused by this sentence, especially about the **"....とはまた違う"** part. Much thanks if anyone can explain to me the sentence's meaning o/

Full sentence below:

> **Aとはまた違うタイプの隙がなく、仕事のできる大人の女性だ**。でも僕にはこうやって優しい顔を見せてくれる。​

Comment: Aとはまた違う is modifying タイプ and I think a comma should be added after タイプの because it doesn't make sense for タイプ to modify 隙...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are four phrases that modify 女性.

- Aとはまた違うタイプの
  of a (yet) different type than A
- 隙がなく
  who has no apparent faults / who is hard to take advantage of
- 仕事のできる
  capable (of doing her job)
- 大人の
  mature/adult
- …女性だ。
  [She] is ... a woman.

The sentence is parsed like so:

> Aとはまた違うタイプの(隙がなく、(仕事のできる(大人の女性)))だ。
>
> She is a mature, capable and apparently flawless woman who is a different type from A.
> She is a different type of woman than A, and is a mature, capable and guarded person.

The use of commas in the original sentence is not very reader-friendly, but you need to try not to be deceived by commas in Japanese. Perhaps it would have been easier for you to parse this sentence if commas had been placed like this:

> Aとはまた違うタイプの、隙がなく、仕事のできる、大人の女性だ。

Comment: JP writers made me suffers even when i knew the meaning of each word ,thanks for your re-phrase !